# getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have included all the libraries including `jason-simple-1.1.1.jar`, `org.json.20120521.jar`. Still I am facing this error:

> getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

I have read the previous answers on this issue but those did not work in my project.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try {

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\google.json"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONObject getSth = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Youtube Data"); //this line fails


    String social = (String) getSth.get("Social media Platform");
    System.out.println(social);
}
```

Comment: Is method `getJSONObject` defined for class `JSONObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because it's attempting to use a mish-mash of the APIs for json-simple and org.json.

The method `getJSONObject(String)` is part of the org.json API.  The rest of your code uses the json-simple API.  It's unfortunate that both libraries have a class named `JSONObject`.  Perhaps this contributes to your confusion.

I don't see the need to have both libraries.  Neither depends on the other. As most of your code uses the json-simple API I would recommend removing org.json from your project (unless another library depends on it), and replacing the line

```
   JSONObject getSth = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Youtube Data"); //this line fails
```

with

```
   JSONObject getSth = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Youtube Data"); //this line hopefully should work
```

Comment: Thank you very much Luke. Your answer resolved the error.